# How to create Node.js Express app serving a Vue.js SPA?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, vue.js, single-page-application

I'm trying to set up a Node.js project that uses Express to provide a few backend APIs and serve a SPA built with Vue.js.

When I use the [Vue cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) to initialize a project, I get e.g. `src/main.ts` main file and commands `npm run serve` to run a dev server and watch for changes and `npm run build` to build a production release.

When I use the [Express application generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) to create a project, I get `./app.js` main file and `npm start` to start the server and watch for changes.

How can I combine these into a single project, both served by the same Express server? Preferably so that a single command would watch + update changes to both server and client?  I want to use Vue single file components and TypeScript, which (probably?) require a build step.

(I don't need dynamic server-side rendering of Vue templates, just the static SPA app provided. I prefer TypeScript, but JavaScript answers are fine as well.)

Comment: So you want a single command that starts both server and client?

Comment: The single command should start the server, which hosts the client. But changes to both should be watched and automatically recompiled.

Answer (score 4):

These will be different for your dev and prod environments...

For development look into [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) - it basically allows you to create a single script in your package.json to start both the client and server concurrently and will watch for changes etc...

For production, you would need something like this in your app.js:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```

(*The code above assumes that your directory structure has a client folder with a build folder after having run `npm run build` I'm more familiar with React than Vue... but the logic should be the same...*)